# 500 Internal server error when trying to call method imagerotate

Tags: php, apache, amazon-ec2, centos7, httpd.conf

I have a PHP script which runs perfectly in our current VPS. But it is giving Internal server error when I run the same script in our new VPS (Amazon).

This script's job is to rotate an image horizontally. But not sure why its giving internal server error. Also, its not logging anything in apache error log. Logging is on in Apache. So, I am clueless what might causing it.

Below is the script and its failing at line `"$rotated = @imagerotate($dst_img, $angle, 0);"`

```
<?php
function RotateJpg($filename = '',$angle = 0,$savename = false){
    header('Content-type: image/png');
    $original   =   @imagecreatefrompng($filename);
    $srcsize = @getimagesize($filename);
    $dest_x = 2000; 
    $dest_y = (2000 / $srcsize[0]) * $srcsize[1]; 
    $dst_img = @imagecreatetruecolor($dest_x, $dest_y);
    @imagecopyresampled($dst_img, $original, 0, 0, 0, 0,$dest_x, $dest_y, $srcsize[0], $srcsize[1]); 
    @imagedestroy($original);
    $rotated    =   @imagerotate($dst_img, $angle, 0);
    @imagedestroy($dst_img);
    if($savename == false) {
        header('Content-Type: image/png');
        @imagepng($rotated);
    }
    else{
        @imagepng($rotated,$savename);
    }        
    imagedestroy($rotated);

}

RotateJpg('source_file',90,'destination_file');
?>
```

I will really appreciate your help.

Regards,

### EDITED

When I am adding below code, its not giving me 500 internal server error but giving 200 success. However it just show me blank page without image rotation.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

I have verified GD is enabled on the server.

Comment: Read your error logs. Without error description you __won't__ get help.

Comment: As long as you keep suppressing errors on every individual function call, you will remain clueless...

Comment: Thanks for your reply @u_mulder. But as I said when I run this script, the errors are not getting logged in apache error_log. However, I have checked logging is on. Please see my edited question.

Comment: @jeroen, Did you mean suppressing errors by @ in my code as highlighted by Thomas Dutrion ?

Comment: Yes. You should also make sure that no output is sent to the browser apart from the image file so you should start with removing the closing php tag. You should also remove the `header` call on top of your function as you are not outputting an image when you use the 3rd parameter.

Comment: @jeroen I have removed header call from top of my function. Also, removed closing php tag but still no luck. Also, I believe no output is being sent to the browser.

Answer (score -1):

You should definitely remove all the `@` from your code (it disables errors and warnings).

My guess would be that GD is not active on the server. You should try to add GD to your php.

Comment: I have tested it by removing @ from the code but still same issue. I also checked GD is enabled on the server.